# App is not opening in ios through branch deeplinking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have already import branch still its giving Use of undeclared identifier 'Branch'.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wthPd.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv07b.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCy89.jpg)

I just want to open the app when we click in quick link created by branch.io

#import <Branch/Branch.h>

[Branch setUseTestBranchKey:YES];
// listener for Branch Deep Link data
[[Branch getInstance] initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary * _Nonnull params, NSError * _Nullable error) {
// do stuff with deep link data (nav to a page, display content, etc)
NSLog(@"%@", params);
}];

Comment: Please provide you code as code blocks, not the screenshots. It's hard to read and it does not get indexed in search. If you have a UI question post a single screenshot as an image, not the link.

Comment: @DiMithras i have add branch in podfile ( pod 'Branch') but i dont know why its showing Use of undeclared identifier 'Branch' in appdelegate file. please help.